# How to combine input values together

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to combine Input values. Below is my working code, any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
getCodeBoxElement(index) {
  return document.getElementById("codeBox" + index);
}

onKeyUpEvent(index, event) {
  const eventCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
console.log((<HTMLInputElement>this.getCodeBoxElement(index)).value);
  if ((<HTMLInputElement>this.getCodeBoxElement(index)).value.length === 1) {
    if (index !== 6) {
      this.getCodeBoxElement(index + 1).focus();

    } else {
      this.getCodeBoxElement(index).blur();
      // Submit code
      // for(var i=0; i<6; i++){

      //           this.verificationCode = (<HTMLInputElement>this.getCodeBoxElement(i)).toString;
      //           console.log(this.verificationCode);

      // }
      console.log("submit code ");
    }
  }
  if (eventCode === 8 && index !== 1) {
    this.getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).focus();
  }
}

onFocusEvent(index) {
  for (var item = 1; item < index; item++) {
    const currentElement = this.getCodeBoxElement(item);
    if (!(<HTMLInputElement>currentElement).value) {
      currentElement.focus();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
 /*     Body Styling only end     */
section {
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; */
  text-align: center;
}
section form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 12px;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
}
section form input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
section form input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
section form input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
section form input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
section form input:focus,
section form input.focus {
  border-color: green;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <form style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <input id="codeBox1" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(1, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(1)" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="codeBox2" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(2, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(2)" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="codeBox3" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(3, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(3)" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="codeBox4" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(4, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(4)" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="codeBox5" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(5, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(5)" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="codeBox6" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(6, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(6)" autocomplete="off">
        <!-- <input id="codeBox5" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(5, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(5)" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="codeBox6" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onKeyUpEvent(6, $event)"
            (focus)="onFocusEvent(6)" autocomplete="off"> -->
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: It would help if you describe your problem a bit more. What does "combine input values" mean?

Comment: Are you *combining* strings or numbers, do you wish for them to be added or just combined together such as a first and last name, `let firstName = "John"; let lastName = "Doe"; let fullName =  firstName + ' ' + LastName;` ***`John Doe`*** or are you combining as in `let x = 2; let y = 2; let z = x + y;` ***`4`*** *Also, you do not need to repeat yourself multiple times in your question as you have done above...

Comment: @dalelandry  ah sorry for the question repeat! I wish if you could combined numbers together such as a  first name and last name

Comment: Parse the numbers as a string...

Comment: @dalelandry how to parse number as a string?

Comment: @AlexWayne Hi my issue is am having 6 inputs boxes  and when you enter number in each separate box  like (1   5   4   6   9   8) the output has to show all together 154698 you execute my script.

Comment: @AlexWayne you can refer to this link https://codepen.io/rajan_r/pen/rNNPVNZ?editors=1111

Comment: @dalelandry hi you can refer to this link https://codepen.io/rajan_r/pen/rNNPVNZ?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

**Inputs return the value of the input as a string by default**... So concatenating the values will combine them by default... If you want to add them as you would numbers, you would need to parse the value as an integer... Otherwise you can simply combine their values by using the plus symbol `+` => `input.value + input2.value`. Even the input type  **number** value will return a string so by concatenating the values together you will be combining their values into one string, this would include numbers with `typeof = string`.

See my example inputs and their outputs for reference...

***EDIT:*** For your issue, you can create an array to hold the value of each input through the iteration in your function... Once you have reached the threshold conditional, join the values of your array.

```js
// create an array to hold your values
let code = new Array;
function onKeyUpEvent(index, event) {
  const eventCode = event.which || event.keyCode; 
  if (getCodeBoxElement(index).value.length === 1) {

     // save the value within your array with each selection
     code[index] = getCodeBoxElement(index).value    
     if (index !== 4) {
        getCodeBoxElement(index+ 1).focus();
     } else {
        getCodeBoxElement(index).blur();         
        // Submit code
        // join the array values into a string using .join('');
        let codeString = code.join('')
        console.log(codeString)
     }
  }
  if (eventCode === 8 && index !== 1) {
     getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).focus();
  }
}
```

```js
function getCodeBoxElement(index) {
  return document.getElementById('codeBox' + index);
}
let code = new Array;

function onKeyUpEvent(index, event) {
  const eventCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (getCodeBoxElement(index).value.length === 1) {
    //code[index] = getCodeBoxElement(index).value also works
    code.push(getCodeBoxElement(index).value)
    if (index !== 4) {
      getCodeBoxElement(index + 1).focus();
    } else {
      getCodeBoxElement(index).blur();
      // Submit code
      let codeString = code.join('');
      let display = document.getElementById('display')
      display.style.color = 'darkgreen';
      display.textContent = `You have entered: ${codeString}`;
    }
  }
  if (eventCode === 8 && index !== 1) {
    getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).focus();
  }
}

function onFocusEvent(index) {
  for (item = 1; item < index; item++) {
    const currentElement = getCodeBoxElement(item);
    if (!currentElement.value) {
      currentElement.focus();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
// Body Styling only Begin ==============
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  font-family: 'POPPINS', Open-Sans;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4568dc, #b06ab3);
}

::selection {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

// Body Styling only End ================
// Container-fluid Styling only Begin ===
.container-fluid {
  .row {
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

// Container-fluid Styling only End =====
// =====
// Passcode-wrapper Styling only Begin ==
.passcode-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  input {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    &::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    &::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      margin: 0;
    }
    &:focus,
    &.focus {
      border-color: green;
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  }
}

// Passcode-wrapper Styling only End ====
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <form class="text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password" class="text-white">Enter 4 Digit Password</label>
          <div class="passcode-wrapper">
            <input id="codeBox1" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(1, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(1)">
            <input id="codeBox2" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(2, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(2)">
            <input id="codeBox3" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(3, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(3)">
            <input id="codeBox4" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(4, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(4)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: okay  what is the exact solution for this

  onKeyUpEvent(index, event) {
    const eventCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if ((<HTMLInputElement>this.getCodeBoxElement(index)).value.length === 1) {
      if (index !== 6) {
        this.getCodeBoxElement(index + 1).focus();
        
      } else {
        this.getCodeBoxElement(index).blur();
        // Submit code
        console.log("submit code ");
      }
    }
    if (eventCode === 8 && index !== 1) {
      this.getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).focus();
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I just did it like this when I did something like this.

```js
document.onkeyup = function() {
  ch = document.getElementsByClassName("ch");
  x = ch.length;
  out = "";
  for (y=0;x>y;y++) {
    out += ch[y].value;
  }
  document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' maxlength='1' class='ch' onkeyup='javascript: if (event.keyCode == 8) { this.previousElementSibling.focus() } else { this.nextElementSibling.focus() }' onfocus='this.select()'><input type='text' maxlength='1' class='ch' onkeyup='javascript: if (event.keyCode == 8) { this.previousElementSibling.focus() } else { this.nextElementSibling.focus() }' onfocus='this.select()'><input type='text' maxlength='1' class='ch' onkeyup='javascript: if (event.keyCode == 8) { this.previousElementSibling.focus() } else { this.nextElementSibling.focus() }' onfocus='this.select()'><input type='text' maxlength='1' class='ch' onkeyup='javascript: if (event.keyCode == 8) { this.previousElementSibling.focus() } else { this.nextElementSibling.focus() }' onfocus='this.select()'>

<span id="final" style="color: green;"></span>
```